# ActionBar.selectTab doesn't refresh spinner in compact mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In an application, I'm using Tabs with the ActionBar, and sometimes I switch tabs programatically using the ActionBar.selectTab() method.

This works well but when the width of the ActionBar is too small, the tabs go in compact mode, and are displayed as a drop down menu. And when I use the ActionBar.selectTab() method, the displayed item in the spinner doesn't change.

Is there an official solution for this or a known workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been asked on [ActionBarSherlock github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/pull/512). It seems that this problem also exists on the ICS ActionBar.

It can be avoided with ABS by changing the source as stated in the link. For the native ActionBar, I managed to make a workaround using reflection to access the action bar's dropdown spinner.

Comment: How u managed to solve this problem. I am using android-support-v4.jar
And facing the same issue. Please refer this question and answer if possible.:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671291/how-to-show-seleceted-fragment-in-action-bar-tab

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Android. Please look at a workaround suggested by Jake Wharton [here:](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38500) and star the issue so it gets fixed