# Navigation Drawer Rotation error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onrestoreinstancestate

After Rotation in my activity that have a NavigationDrawer there is error in `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setSelectedNavigationIndex not valid for current navigation mode
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(WindowDecorActionBar.java:420)
            at ir.parsdroid.telegrameducation.Tools.enhanced.onRestoreInstanceState(enhanced.java:118)
```

My code:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Serialize the current dropdown position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM,
                getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }
```

I think Logic that says here is true but I don't know how to use it for NavigationDrawer:
[How to show selected fragment in action bar tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671291/how-to-show-selected-fragment-in-action-bar-tab)

Comment: Maybe you forgot to call setNavigationMode in onCreate() ?

And setSelectedNavigationItem is deprecated from api 21. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem(int)

Comment: no diference with calling setNavigationMode or call nothing in onCreate(). see my edit pls.