# How can I open fragment of tabs when I pressed notification?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-notifications, android-tablayout

I am trying launch notification in one tabs fragment. I need to open specific tab when I click notification. I tried like this.

in notification

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationTabs.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    intent.putExtra("Medicine", "Medicine");
    //intent.putExtra("text", "need to take medicine");
    // intent.setAction("Medicine");
    // Open NotificationView.java Activity
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and in main tab activity

```
public class NotificationTabs extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
ActionBar actionBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_tabs);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    tabLayout =(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    int position = 0;

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String intentaction = intent.getAction();

    if (intentaction != null) {
        if (intentaction.equals("Medicine")) {
            position = 2;
        }
    }
     actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);//--- here i got error
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new QuizFragment(),"Quiz");
    adapter.addFragment(new TipsFragment(),"Tips" );
    adapter.addFragment(new MedicineFragment(),"Medicine");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {

        super(manager);
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Please any one can help how can I open fragment when I click notification?in my code. Whenever I pressed notification I need to come Medicine Fragment in android. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: GCM+Alarm Notification

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getStringExtra();
```

like this

```
String name = data.getStringExtra("Medicine");
```

Comment: getting this error:   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setSelectedNavigationIndex not valid for current navigation mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671291/how-to-show-selected-fragment-in-action-bar-tab Look here

Comment: And dont open it in landscape mode

Comment: Check the link, someone solved your problem just copy last 2 code parts of his answer

Comment: no thats won't work in my code both were different. that is for onpagelistener.but my need from notification

Comment: Add this under getActionBar()                actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: If you get an error again change it to. actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

Answer (score 0):

Pass action specifying tab to open, along with intent in pending intent. And in your activity retrieve action (see getIntent()) passed and based on it, open a specific tab.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationTabs.class);
intent.setAction("Medicine");
PendingIntent pending intent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);              



 public class NotificationTabs extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_tabs);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        tabLayout =(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);







    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new QuizFragment(),"Quiz");
        adapter.addFragment(new TipsFragment(),"Tips" );
        adapter.addFragment(new MedicineFragment(),"Medicine");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       if(getIntent().getAction().equals("Medicine") {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);


        }else{
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
        }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//here you have to notify      the adapter
    }
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {

            super(manager);
        }
        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i open tab?  actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position) here how can i get position

Comment: in your NotificationTabs onCreate you have to write this line if(getIntent().getAction().equals("OPEN_TAB_1") {
     // here you pass the fragment tab
}

Comment: ya i get it here like this but in my case  if(getIntent().getAction().equals("Medicine") {  here how can i open tab?}

Comment: then you have to set the fragment in it , this two lines adapter.addFragment(new MedicineFragment(),"Medicine");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I have one idea ,don't know right or wrong you can test it once and tell me it worked for you or not ,i am updating my previous code

Comment: private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        if(getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Quiz")) {
            adapter.addFragment(new QuizFragment(), "Quiz");
        }else if(getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Tips")) {
            adapter.addFragment(new TipsFragment(), "Tips");
      }
        else if (getIntent().getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("Medicine")) {
            adapter.addFragment(new MedicineFragment(),"Medicine"); }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);} nowi updated like this in my code

Comment: already i worked like that but its giving error like this   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setSelectedNavigationIndex not valid for current navigation mode
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(ToolbarActionBar.jav

Comment: you are implementing toolbar aswell as actionbar so that you are getting the above error

Comment: so there is no need to implement tool bar? i removed toolbar also . then i am getting this error The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 3, found: 4 Pager id: testing.amaze.com.medicine:id/viewpager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class testing.amaze.com.medicine.NotificationTabs$ViewPagerAdapter
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1000)

Comment: Expected adapter item count: 3, found: 4 ?? why you are getting 4 item

Comment: if(getIntent().getAction().equals("Medicine") {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);


        }else{
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
        }notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: if(getIntent().getAction().equals("Medicine") ){  actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
  }else{
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
        }
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and getting error like this Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at testing.amaze.com.medicine.NotificationTabs.onCreate(NotificationTabs.java:55)

Comment: and also have doubt .whatsapp also working with toolbar.then what is the problem with it?

Comment: I have Updated the code , whatsapp is using Material designing and they are not using actionbar

Comment: i did like that also and now i am also doing in metarial design

Comment: you have teamviewer or any other resource i can connect it to you,coz i am leaving from the office, at night i will try it out

Comment: yaa.. i have teamviewer

Comment: ok at night i will connect to you ,you can give reply to sr.amitranjan@gmail.com ,i will ping you at night after 2 hours

Comment: it's my pleasure :) gtg bbye take care

Answer (score 0):

sample

return new Intent(MyApplication.getContext(), DepositCLIA.class).setAction("tab2deposit");

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String intentaction = intent.getAction();
    if (intentaction != null) {
        if (intentaction.equals("tab2deposit")) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some narrative to your answer. Answers with just code will get deleted.